# Storing data in local folder is limited

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to save data locally to my device app folder.

When I try to save collected data on an actual Android smartphone, it doesn't work. It is limited by name and filetype, as I cannot change it from `test.txt` and it is limited in string length, as a maximum of twelve characters get saved.

I have the acquired the following permissions:

```cs
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is my code:

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
private async void ExportData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = await App.Database.GetDataAsync();
        DependencyService.Get<IFileService>().CreateFile(items);
    }
```

**Interface**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace LocationApp.Interface
{
    public interface IFileService
    {
        void CreateFile(List<LocationData> items);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```cs
using Android.App;
using LocationApp.Droid;
using LocationApp.Interface;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

[assembly:Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(FileService))]
namespace LocationApp.Droid
{
    public class FileService : IFileService
    {
        public string GetRootPath()
        {
            return Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).ToString();
        }

        public void CreateFile(List<LocationData> items)
        {
            var fileName = "test-file.txt";
            var destination = Path.Combine(GetRootPath(), fileName);
            string[] text = new string[items.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                text[i] = $"{items[i].Latitude},{items[i].Longitude},{items[i].Day},{items[i].Time}";
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(destination, text);
        }
    }
}
```

I also attempted to see what would happen to an emulator, I used a Pixel 2 with Android 9.0, API 28 where I got the following error:
`[ContextImpl] Failed to ensure /storage/120E-0B1B/Android/data/com.companyname.locationapp/files: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to prepare /storage/120E-0B1B/Android/data/com.companyname.locationapp/files/: android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code -13)`

In the end, I only care about putting all my data in a single file. The filename or the error on my emulator I provided in case the error is based on that. If not, I do not care if they are fixed/fixable.

Comment: In the properties of your Android project try to check the ```READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE``` permissions.

Comment: I forgot to include that in the context, thank you for the notice!

Comment: What kind of device are you using that GetExternalFilesDir() would return a path on a removable micro sd card as /storage/120E-0B1B/Android/data/.... would be on one. Further you do not need any permission to use paths returned by getExternalFilesDir() and/or getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: Confusing post. You should not have started with that emulator as what is what? And what is limited? A file name? How? Please elaborate. Are you closing the file when writing is done?

Comment: For the emulator I am using a Pixel 2 with Android 9.0, API 28. For the real life testing I am using a Galaxy S10 SM g973f running on Android 11.0.99 - API 31. Yeah I don't think it's a permission issue either, as the app has full storage permissions on the device.

Comment: The file name can only be `test.txt`, otherwise the smartphone does not save it. I have not closed the file when writing is done, I'll look into that.

Comment: there are numerous changes to external storage access in recent versions of Android

Comment: You say that you want to access  app’s folder. That isn’t what your code does - you are accessing external storage. Probably should read up on difference between app private storage, non-private internal storage, and external storage. Start with the sample code reachable from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I created a simple demo, and it works on my android emulator(android 11) .

You can test on your side.

The code is:

```
    public void CreateFile(List<LocationData> items)
    {
        var fileName = "test-file.txt";

        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

        var destination = Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);
        string[] text = new string[items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            text[i] = $"{items[i].Latitude},{items[i].Longitude}";
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(destination, text);
    }
```

And after I saved the data,I could get the saved data by the following code(the filename is `test-file.txt`):

```
    public string ReadData(string filename)
    {
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
        return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }
```